# Python hangman replacing

Tags: python

So I'm writing a hangman program and I'm having trouble getting the current guesses to display as underscores with the correct letters guessed replacing an underscore. I can get the function to work once (thats the insert_letter function) and I know its just replacing every time it goes through the loop, but I can't return the new current without quitting the loop so if someone could offer another way to get the guesses to keep updating that would be great!

```
def insert_letter(letter, current, word):
    current = "_" * len(word)
    for i in range (len(word)):
        if letter in word[i]:
             current = current[:i] + letter + current[i+1:]
    return current 



def play_hangman(filename, incorrect):
    words = read_words(filename)
    secret_word = random.choice(words)
    num_guess = 0 
    letters_guessed = set()
    letter = input("Please enter a letter: ") 
    while num_guess < incorrect:
        letter = input() 
        if letter in secret_word:
            current = insert_letter(letter, current, secret_word)
            print(current)  
        else:
            num_guess += 1
            current = "_" * len(secret_word)
            print(current)  
        letters_guessed.add(letter)
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show the code for your `insert_letter()` function so I wrote an alternative -- `display_remaining()`.  Give this a try:

```
import random, sys

def play_hangman(filename, incorrect):
    words = read_words(filename)
    secret_word = random.choice(words)
    num_guess = 0 
    letters_guessed = set()
    while num_guess < incorrect:
        letter = input("Please enter a letter: ") 
        letters_guessed.add(letter)
        current = display_remaining(secret_word, letters_guessed)
        print(current)
        if not letter in secret_word:
            print("Incorrect guess.")
            num_guess += 1
        if not '_' in current:
            print("Congratulations! You've won!")
            sys.exit(0)
    print("Sorry. You've run out of guesses. Game over.")

def display_remaining(word, guessed):
    replaced = word[:]
    for letter in word:
        if (not letter == '_') and letter not in guessed:
            replaced = replaced.replace(letter, '_', 1)
    return replaced

def read_words(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rU') as f:
        return [line.strip() for line in f]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    play_hangman('words.txt', 6)
```

**NOTE:** With this implementation, your words file shouldn't have any words containing the underscore character.

Comment: That will still override current every time the function iterates through

Comment: Did you run it? Works fine for me.